# "Acces denied " message in Services just showed up

Tags: windows-xp, services

I have Windows XP SP3 and Avast antivirus on my notebook. So problem is that from yesterday I started to see message " Access denied" when I try to do anything with any service (Disable, Manual, Automatic).

I've done System restore a week a go, but 2 or 3 days ago the issues has occurred again. Should I make System Restore again?  What could possibly be a reason?

Comment: You may have a virus. You may have a program not detected as a virus which is being run and making this happen. Try an online scan, something like http://www.bitdefender.co.uk/scanner/online/free.html and see if this helps or detects anything. Lastly, what is the full error message you are getting?

Comment: Do you have an HP printer? And after you fixed the error the first time and after you did a system restore, did you do another Windows Update?

Comment: I don't have a HP printer on this laptop . I used System restore point and it worked. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing other forums with similar issues it appears as if the error could be due to a conflict with a piece of software. One forum has mentioned it was due to a security update for their printer!

Disable ZoneAlarm or any firewall/AV you have and see if the error persists.

Open up MSCONFIG and, if you know what you are doing (if not, read up on it first) disable as much as you can from start up. If the problem goes then you'll have to add them one at a time until you find the culprit!

A Windows Update security update or similar could cause the issue. Roll back the system (System restore) and only download the updates you need.